# How to validate spring security antmatcher in a custom filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have defined a custom filter, i added just after BasicAutenticationFilter...

Issue is, when i ping my microservice (by the health check of rancher in this case) it always go to the filter, and do stuff is suppose it shouldn't, I say it suppose it shouldn't because i put the ping into the antmatchers to permitAll requests, the code in my filter is this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.debug(this + "received authentication request from " + request.getRemoteHost() + " to " + request.getLocalName());

    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        if (isAuthenticationRequired()) {
            authenticate(request,response);
        } else {
            logger.debug("session already contained valid Authentication - not checking again");
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}   

private boolean isAuthenticationRequired() {
    Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if ((existingAuth == null) || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I assumed, when you SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); it should validate the antmatchers and return existingAuth with true, i know  i know this is to magical to think as i do, but then, i need to find a away to validate the request and tell spring security is inside the antmatchers list..

Comment: It goes through your filter, because you created the filter. That's okay. Did you check, what your `isAuthenticationRequired` returns? It should return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the filter to do the health check. place it in position [FIRST](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/b83c8c198a32525d7c6da5db86af59d9879e7046/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SecurityConfig.java?ts=4#L53)

```
public class HealthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private String healthPath = "/healthcheck/**";
    private AntPathRequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(healthPath);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (matcher.matches(request)) { //evaluate health check
            //do anything you want over here.
            //including performing your health check
            response.getWriter().write("OK");
            response.setStatus(200);
        }
        else {
            //only execute the other filters if we're not doing a health check
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Online [integration tests are available](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/b83c8c198a32525d7c6da5db86af59d9879e7046/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/HealthCheckTests.java?ts=4#L30)